# jQuery enlarge image but keep centered

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to have an image enlarge using jQuery while keeping it centered. I've tried adding a `'right'` animation property, but it hasn't helped.

[Here](http://northviewhigh.com/index/graduation/tickets/) is the live version of the page. Click on Student or Guest to see the animation.

jQuery:

```
var studFocusWidth = 1000;
var studFocusChange = 165;
var chartSpeed = 700;

function goToStud() {
    $('#chart').attr("usemap", "studmap")
    .animate({
        'width': studFocusWidth,
        'right': studFocusChange
    }, chartSpeed)
    .attr("src", "images/chartsfocus.png");

    $('h3').html("Select a Section");
    $('#chartback').addClass("studback").fadeIn(chartSpeed);

}

// There is a second function for the guest section
```

HTML:

```
<div id="chartframe">
    <!-- image maps omitted -->
    <img id="chart" src="images/chartstart.png" usemap="#chartmap" alt="Chart" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#chartframe {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;
}

#chart {
    width:640px;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: I see the image enlarged and centered in Firefox and Chrome. You should specify `'px'` in your `goToSutd()` function for `width` and `right`. Be clear about what the problem is.

Comment: Yeah, like @eicto said, `.animate` doesn't need px. What I guess the problem really is that the animation isn't smooth... It jumps left before it starts enlarging so it looks weird. I want it to simply zoom  in but remain centered throughout the animation.

Comment: True that `px` is not needed, however if the units are `em` or `%` then they need to be specified. Cheers!

Comment: I added `+ "px"` onto the `studFocus*` lines and it doesn't make a difference. It still jumps to the left when you click the button.

Comment: Maybe reduce the size of the images your using. Is `1792 x 1054` really necessary for the defined space of `640px` width?

Comment: I'm using a Macbook Pro with Retina display so I'm accounting for the extra DPI.

Comment: Since you've defined `640px` fixed width, the gargantuan images then needs to be processed by the browser to make it smaller. Try and use an appropriate image size to see if it makes a positive difference in animation and in downloading them as well. *Image swaps on images as humongous as those could be the culprit.* To be clear: You have over `14MB` of image data alone!

Comment: I've uploaded smaller versions and that didn't seem to help...

Comment: I do see an improvement in that the initial `hover` does not cause glitchy reloading of image. Do you also have smaller versions for the `/hover/` images as well?

Comment: I can do that too but that won't fix the resizing issues, will it? I'll disable that hover and see.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21592/discussion-between-kobi-tate-and-arttronics)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**jsFiddle ZOOM Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/UTceF/1/)

As per previous comments including [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21592/discussion-between-kobi-tate-and-arttronics), changing out the **`28`** extremely large images (**@ 1792 x 1054**) for smaller ones will not only increase loading time of those images (*that's 14 MB just in 28 images*), it will also help prevent visual artifacts when doing *image swaps* for your `image map` (i.e., seating area photo).

Since the maximum width you have defined is `600px`, the exact size required for the images width depends on how much ZOOM you are going to use... so that the visual quality is retained when used at that zoomed level. For a general example, if you were going to zoom the image `200%`, then the maximum width of the images should be `1200px` (`600px` times 2, where `600px` is your container `div` with fixed `width`).

Most likely, you will not zoom that large, so use percentages in calculating the final width. If your zooming 25% larger, then it's `600px times 25% which gives you 150px`, then that `150px` is added to the container `div width of 600px`, which gives you an image width of `750px`. You just shaved **over** `1000px` of unnecessary image `width` data.

As far as the **jQuery zoom animation** you currently have, it is correct for you to animate both the `width` and the `height` at the same time. That however does not solve the *centering* of the `image map` as it's zooming, which causes a mis-alignment to be visually noticable.

The best solution in that case, per our comments in chat, is to progress from `CSS` to `CSS3` and use **zoom techniques** via **`transform:scale()`** property. It's friendly in all modern browsers and takes care of **centering** while the object is **zooming**, all *simultaneously*.

The jsFiddle above servers as an example for [this online demo](http://www.solucior.com/15-Zoom_with_CSS3.html) so you can substituent your `image map` markup instead.

Comment: I implemented this on the Student section, and it's working quite well! My only concern is the compatibility with IE9 and older. According to [CanIUse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=transition), only IE10 is compatible with CSS Transitions. What is the best way to get around this?

Comment: The online demo explains it's IE9 compatible because instead of using `transform:scale` it uses it's Microsoft CSS equivalent `filter:`. To keep the jsFiddle short, I only included markup for Firefox and Chrome for jQuery Zoom (however, IE9 filter is present for pure CSS3 zoom). For IE9: Access any PC with Vista or higher and view the online demo to understand how the page reacts to that browser. For IE8: Access any PC with Windows XP. I noticed in IE8 that the 1st example "works somewhat" in that it pops to the zoomed level (without animation) for the demo page while the 2nd example fails.

Comment: To truly have a zoomed effect from the webpage seating area in all browsers, including IE8, the only way I see this is to have a lightbox that specializes in zooming the element to any size you need while allowing you to interact inside of that. Look at the [**2nd image**](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples) to see it zoom off the page in this *Fancybox 2* online demo. Note you can change the click event to `mouseover` to initiate the lightbox. You can also force that the box is not closeable using the `[x]` or `[esc]` keys, so that only your `[button]` closes it. It zooms in IE8 too!